# How to check if other end of a socket has been accepted?

Tags: c, linux, sockets, unix-socket

I have a client/server set up and I want my client to know if the server has accepted the connection. Otherwise my client has no clue it's still waiting to be accepted. I can't rely on further communication (protocol specification) to verify this. So for example sending a "Good to go" string from the server to the client is not an option. Is there a flag or something that I can check to see if the server is indeed receiving? Some example code follows:

```
/* Client */
...
getaddrinfo(ip, port, &hints, &servinfo);
connect(sockfd, info->ai_addr, info->ai_addrlen);

if (info == NULL) {
    printf("connection failure\n");
    exit(1);
}

inet_ntop(info->ai_family, get_in_addr((struct sockaddr *)info->ai_addr), ipstring, sizeof(ipstring));
printf("Connected to %s!\n", ipstring);
...

/* Server */
...
pause(); /* If don't accept the connection, how to make the client know? */ 
new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&cli_addr, &addr_size);
...
```

Comment: If it hasn't accepted, there is no connection and it will time out on the client end. You'd need an other connection to do what you want, which would just move the problem. In order to send it hasn't accepted, it would need to accept the connection to do it...

Comment: It is in mostly in any case a good idea to check the return value of system calls. And if such indicate an error, checking the value of `errno`, if the man page states it is set on error, will give even more enlightening.

Comment: I already check everything, they weren't included for brevity.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of backlog, server can send SYN-ACK before accept call. So Client call `connect()` can return before server calls `accept()`.

As you say: "Good to go" message from the server is not option.
How about: "echo" request from client. So Server will respond after accept.

If any extra traffic in the TCP stream is not an option. Can you use ancillary data?

Comment: I believe ancillary data would be acceptable, and even if not, I would  still really like to know how this approach would solve this problem. Would you be so kind as to provide an example?

Comment: @SKi Doubling on vascop request here, would be nice to have an implementation example of what you call "an echo request".

Answer (score 2):

you should check the return value from `connect()` since it will indicate via `errno` why it failed.

The `connect()` call in your case will timeout and therefor `connect()` will return `-1` and `errno` is set to `ETIMEDOUT`

```
  int ret = connect(sockfd, info->ai_addr, info->ai_addrlen);
  if (ret == -1) {
      /* connect failed */
      switch(errno) {
      case ETIMEDOUT:
             /* your server didn't accept the connection */
      case ECONNREFUSED:
             /* your server isn't listening yet, e.g. didn't start */
      default:
             /* any other error, see man 2 connect */
      }
  }
```

Comment: Ah, my bad. I forgot to include that I had a backlog in place to make sure I don't drop any connections. Would I be better off dropping the backlog and implementing some kind of exponential retry method to connect on the client side?

Comment: than checking for `ETIMEDOUT` should do the job. Another option would be to rewrite the server application to handle the connections async and accept the connections for later handling. You might want to take a look at [libevent](http://libevent.org/).

Comment: The limiting factor for no more clients does not lie with the sockets so ETIMEDOUT is never fired. I'll look into libevent to see if they have any implementation of what I need, thanks